# Tricky Multiple Groupings and Transformations using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I have a dataset where I would like to:

1. group by location and box and take **distinct** count of the box
2. create column headers with the values in the status column and include its count based on the box

### Data

```
ID  location    type    box     status          
aa  NY          no      box55   hey         
aa  NY          no      box55   hi          
aa  NY          yes     box66   hello           
aa  NY          yes     box66   goodbye         
aa  CA          no      box11   hey         
aa  CA          no      box11   hi          
aa  CA          yes     box11   hello           
aa  CA          yes     box11   goodbye         
aa  CA          no      box86   hey         
aa  CA          no      box86   hi          
aa  CA          yes     box86   hello           
aa  CA          yes     box99   goodbye         
aa  CA          no      box99   hey         
aa  CA          no      box99   hi
```

### Desired

```
location    box count   box     hey hi  hello   goodbye 
NY          2           box55   1   1   0       0   
NY          2           box66   0   0   1       1   
CA          3           box11   1   1   1       1   
CA          3           box86   1   1   1       0   
CA          3           box99   1   1   0       1
```

### Doing

```
df['box count'] = df.groupby(['location','box'])['box'].size()


t = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep='', prefix='', 
columns=['status']).groupby(['box', 'location'], 
as_index=False).sum().assign(count=df.groupby(['box', 'location'],
as_index=False)['status'].size()['size'])
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making two dataframes: first with `.groupby()`, second with `pd.crosstab`. Then just `pd.concat` them:

```py
df1 = df.groupby(["location", "box"]).agg(**{"box count": ("box", "size")})
df2 = pd.crosstab([df["location"], df["box"]], df["status"])

df_out = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(df_out.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
  location    box  box count  goodbye  hello  hey  hi
0       CA  box11          4        1      1    1   1
1       CA  box86          3        0      1    1   1
2       CA  box99          3        1      0    1   1
3       NY  box55          2        0      0    1   1
4       NY  box66          2        1      1    0   0
```

---

EDIT:

```
m = df.groupby(["location"])["box"].nunique()
df1 = df.groupby(["location", "box"]).agg(
    **{
        "box count": (
            "location",
            lambda x: m[x.iat[0]],
        )
    }
)
df2 = pd.crosstab([df["location"], df["box"]], df["status"])

df_out = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(df_out.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
  location    box  box count  goodbye  hello  hey  hi
0       CA  box11          3        1      1    1   1
1       CA  box86          3        0      1    1   1
2       CA  box99          3        1      0    1   1
3       NY  box55          2        0      0    1   1
4       NY  box66          2        1      1    0   0
```

Comment: Hi @Andrej the CA count should be 3. We see there are 3 distinct boxes in CA (box11, box86, and box99)